# How to display frontend plugin in different layouts in TYPO3?

Tags: typo3, typo3-7.6.x

I have a TYPO3 frontend plugin and now I want two different ways to display the "list" controller. How can I achieve this?

Comment: There are several ways. Question: should an editor be able to control/set kind of diplay? In such case you need to store this setting together with the plugin in table tt_content. feks pi_flexform.

Comment: yes you should be able to decide which layout is displayed wehen you add the plugin to a page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `flexform` for frontend plugin like below.

In your ext_tables.php file.

```php
//extenstion name
$extensionName = \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility::underscoredToUpperCamelCase($_EXTKEY);

//plugin integration
$frontendpluginName = 'Plugin name';
$pluginSignature = strtolower($extensionName) . '_'.strtolower(
    $frontendpluginName
);

$GLOBALS['TCA']['tt_content']['types']['list']['subtypes_addlist'][$pluginSignature] = 'pi_flexform';
\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::addPiFlexFormValue(
    $pluginSignature,
    'FILE:EXT:' . $_EXTKEY . '/Configuration/FlexForms/configure.xml'
);
```

Now create `configure.xml` file on this path `/Configuration/FlexForms/`

```xml
<T3DataStructure>
    <sheets>
        <!--
            ################################
              SHEET General Settings
            ################################
        -->
        <sDEF>
            <ROOT>
                <TCEforms>
                    <sheetTitle>General</sheetTitle>
                </TCEforms>
                <type>array</type>
                <el>
                    <!-- View -->
                    <settings.layout>
                      <TCEforms>
                        <label>Select Frontend Layout</label>
                        <config>
                          <type>select</type>
                          <items>
                            <numIndex index="0">
                              <numIndex index="0">Layout 1</numIndex>
                              <numIndex index="1">1</numIndex>
                            </numIndex>
                            <numIndex index="1">
                              <numIndex index="0">Layout 2</numIndex>
                              <numIndex index="1">2</numIndex>
                            </numIndex>
                          </items>
                          <size>10</size>
                          <minitems>0</minitems>
                          <maxitems>1</maxitems>
                          <suppress_icons>1</suppress_icons>
                        </config>
                      </TCEforms>
                    </settings.layout>
                </el>               
            </ROOT>
        </sDEF>
    </sheets>
</T3DataStructure>
```

Now use this value in frontend template files like below.

```xml
<f:if condition="{settings.layout} == 1">
  <f:then>
    Layout 1 html
  </f:then>
  <f:else>
    Layout 2 html
  </f:else>
</f:if>
```

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used this in a while so I am not 100% this is still relevant, the API docs suggest that you can still do this though:

```
public function listAction() {

  {your_code}

  $this->view->setTemplatePathAndFilename(
          'typo3conf/ext/' .
          $this->request->getControllerExtensionKey() .
          '/{path_to}/OtherTemplate.html');

  $this->view->assign(...);

}
```

If you need to switch this on a per plugin base decide which template to use by reading a configuration variable.

Comment: and how do I tell the plugin when Its adde to call another Action?

Comment: You can use FlexForm to add the setting as described in the answer above.